# What is the difference between useTheme and createMiuiTheme in material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

"I am confused between useTheme and createMiuiTheme ."

Comment: first, Use a theme, and second create a theme.

Comment: `createMiuiTheme` creates the `theme` object. `useTheme` allows you to access that `theme` object inside function components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useTheme` is a hook used to access Material UI theme in the React components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return <div>{`spacing ${theme.spacing}`}</div>;
}
```

Where as,

`createMuiTheme` is used to create, mostly override the Material UI theme to a specific component or the whole React app theme.

```
import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import {
  createMuiTheme,
  makeStyles,
  createStyles,
  Theme as AugmentedTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { orange } from '@material-ui/core/colors';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
  interface Theme {
    status: {
      danger: string;
    };
  }
  // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
  interface ThemeOptions {
    status?: {
      danger?: string;
    };
  }
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: AugmentedTheme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      color: theme.status.danger,
      '&$checked': {
        color: theme.status.danger,
      },
    },
    checked: {},
  }),
);

function CustomCheckbox() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Checkbox
      defaultChecked
      classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        checked: classes.checked,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```